# Did Uthman admit that the Qur'an has errors?

Tags: uloom-al-quran

I had recently came across this narration from [Abu Ubayd Al-Qasims Fadail Al-Quran, hadith 468](http://islamport.com/d/1/ajz/1/357/992.html):

> حدثنا أبو عبيد قال : حدثنا حجاج ، عن هارون بن موسى ، قال : أخبرني
> الزبير بن الخريت ، عن عكرمة ، قال : لما كتبت المصاحف عرضت على عثمان ،
> فوجد فيها حروفا من اللحن ، فقال : « لا تغيروها فإن العرب ستغيرها ، أو
> قال : ستعربها بألسنتها ، لو كان الكاتب من ثقيف ، والمملي من هذيل لم
> توجد فيه هذه الحروف »
>
> Abu Ubaid <– Hajjaj <– Harun bin Musa <– Al-Zubayr bin Al-Khairat <–
> Ikrimah: When the Musahif was written, it was presented to Uthman. He
> found some errors and said “do not change them for the Arabs will soon
> change them”. Or he said: “They will correctly pronounce them via
> their tongues. Had the scribe been from the tribe of Thaqif, and the
> one who dictates it from the tribe of Hudhayl, these letters would not
> be found in it”.

Can someone please explain the context he said this in.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/135752/

Comment: That's a very good explanation of that Hadith @UmH